# php/mysql oop using prepared statement review

Tags: php, oop, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to implement prepared statement but for some reason I am not able to create user. Note, I have already been able to create user with same values in the old tradition fation [mysql_connect and ...] Could some body help me identify where I am making my mistake?

```
require_once 'config.php';
class AuthDb {
private $db;
function __construct(){
    $this->db = mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) 
                or die('could not connect');        
}

function __destruct(){

    $this->db->close();
    unset($this->db);
}

public function createUser($name, $email) {

    $query = "INSERT INTO myUsers (name, email) VALUES (?, ?)";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $name, $email);
    if ($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }

    return false;

  }

}

$create = new AuthDb();
$name = "bing";
$email = "banbang@yahoo.com"; 
$test = $create->createUser($name, $email);
```

Comment: `$this->db = mysqli(DB_SERVER` - did you forget a `new` here?

Comment: mysqli is a function, why would I need to instantiate it?

Comment: I was just curious because there is a class called `mysqli` and `config.php` didn't sound like it would provide a function called mysqli(...) ;-)

Comment: you are actually right, I have to add new before mysqli(...). I have made a change but i still can't insert into database.

Comment: In that case `new mysqli... or die(...)` won't work as intended. You get a "valid" mysqli object even if the connection failed. You have to check `$this->db->error` and/or `$this->db->errno`. see docs.php.net/mysqli.construct (or use PDO instead).

Comment: oh and btw: you might want to consider not instantiating the mysqli object within AuthDB but "inject" it into the object (and by that make the dependency/coupling less tight), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with more error handling/logging.

```
define('DEBUG_LOG', true);
function onError($general, $details) {
    echo '<pre>', htmlentities($general), "</pre>\n";
    if ( defined('DEBUG_LOG') && DEBUG_LOG ) {
        echo '<pre>', htmlentities($details), "</pre>\n";
        echo '<pre>'; debug_print_backtrace(); echo "</pre>\n";
    }
    die;
}

class AuthDb {
[...]
    public function createUser($name, $email) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO myUsers (name, email) VALUES (?, ?)";
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        if ( !$stmt ) {
            onError('database error', $this->db->errno .': '.$this->db->error);
            return false;
        }

        $rc = $stmt->bind_param("ss", $name, $email);
        if ( !$rc ) {
            onError('database error', 'bind failed');
            return false;
        }

        if ( !$stmt->execute() ) {
            onError('database error', $stmt->errno.': '.$stmt->error );
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, for the help, I was able to finally add the name and email into the database. This is a good debugging mechanism, I have to learn more OOP, specially for the debugging.